# Dividing with a user input in Python 3.3.0 works but not with 3.3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

When writing up a program in python version 3.3.0 (because of non-admin privileges i can't update) it worked completely fine, however now that i am using python version 3.3.2 it no longer works, the program goes as follows:

```
num = input("please enter a value and press enter: ")
```

(assuming 1 is chosen)

```
conv = input("what unit is the measurement in? cm, m, or km: ")
```

(assuming cm is chosen)

```
if conv == "cm":
print("chosen value is cm, converting to m and km")
m = num/100
print(m , "meters")
km = num/100000
print(km , "kilometers")
```

the desired output is (found in 3.3.0):

```
please enter value and press enter: 1
your chosen value is:  1
what unit is the measurement in? cm, m, or km: cm
you have chosen cm, converting to m and km
0.01 meters
1e-05 kilometers
```

but instead i get (in 3.3.2):

```
please enter value and press enter: 1
your chosen value is:  1
what unit is the measurement in? cm, m, or km: cm
you have chosen cm, converting to m and km
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/QUESTION.py", line 10, in <module>
m = num/100
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: your traceback error and your posted code do not match. Are you really using python3 and not python2?

Comment: Convery `num` to an integer value. `num = int(num);` You are attempting to divide a string.

Comment: sorry, i didn't change that part of the code to the updated one, "data" is actually "num" , and, as far as i can tell, it is definitely python3 (as it states: Python 3.3.2 Shell. whenever i open IDLE

Comment: Okay, open the version of python that runs this code, and type `import sys; print(sys.version)`, what does it say?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49567445/edit) to include more information.

Comment: Fairly sure the same error will pop up in 3.3.0

Comment: Thank you everyone for taking some time to help me with my problem, it is now fixed thanks to Matt Clark
COLDSPEED: the output is as follows -
On version that didnt work 
3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)

and
On version that worked
3.3.0 (default, Mar 12 2018, 10:33:20) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)]

Comment: @zorua98741 How does that work? That's not 3.3.0, how isn't it throwing errors for you?

Comment: @COLDSPEED i don't see why it would change anything but one is on "Compatible Apple" and the other isn't. not sure why that would matter but what else would change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised that it works somewhere anyway. When using the `input()` function, Python [returns a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) (`str`) from what has been entered.

So basically, you just need to convert the text to an integer, using `num = int(num)` after having initialized your `num` variable. To be clean, you'd also need to implement a basic error handling system, in case the input entered by the user is not implicitely convertable to an integer.

For example:

```
num = ""
while not isinstance(num, int):
    num = input("Please, enter a number\n>>> ")
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        pass
# proceed with your code...
```